# Change all UIViewControllers Backgrounds

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change all my project's UIViewControllers, so I have this:

```
let bg = BackgroundImage().backgroundImage
bg.alpha = 0.2
bg.frame = self.view.frame

let wBg = UIView()
wBg.frame = self.view.frame
wBg.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)

self.view.addSubview(wBg)
self.view.sendSubview(toBack: wBg)

self.view.addSubview(bg)
self.view.sendSubview(toBack: bg)
```

Where `BackgroundImage().backgroundImage` returns a UIImageView.

But how can I implement this on all my UIViewControllers without having to copy/paste the same in all my VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a function in a `UIViewController` extension. This function should setup the view controller's background as needed.

Then in the `viewDidLoad` function of each of your view controllers you can call that extension function.

Comment: GREAT! I created an `BgImage+UIViewcontroller.swift` extension then created the function setBackgroundImage() and done! Thanks @rmaddy!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Create BaseViewController.swift**

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        setBackgroundImage()
    }

    setBackgroundImage() {

    }
}
```

**2. Other ViewController will inherit the BaseViewController**

```
class TimelinesViewController: BaseViewController {

}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work for table view controllers and collection view controllers and others.